# unity game in raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

i create a game in unity Unity 5.4.1f1 using windows ,i build the game for the Linux devices with x86 bit and 64bit but when i launch the app in raspberry he can't now the type of file and tell me to choose application
[image]
Someone can give me a solution or a program can read the x86 bit

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Care to tell why you've rolled back the edit that made the post somewhat more comprehensible?

Answer (score 3):

Raspberry Pi isn't a x86 machine, it's using the ARM architecture, maybe try compiling for ARM.

Comment: There is a solution or a virtual machinr that running in pc i find wine and exagear but it's not free there is a trial version??

Comment: bochs could possibly emulate an X86 on the Pi, but it will be *slow*. Wine is free, buth translates API calls, not CPU instructions. In short: you **have** to recompile it for arm to run it, realistically speaking.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,can bochs run with vnc viewer using my desktop

Comment: I find a way to runnig windows 10 iot core in the raspberry ,can windows 10 running x86bit software ?

Comment: No, Windows IoT is specifically compiled for ARM architecture and thus runs only ARM applications.